# @login_required page blank when log in

Tags: python, django, authentication, login-required

I have made a @login_required for a blog post so the user has to login to see it, but it seems to login but the page that comes up is blank. However when I look at the url it says I'm on the page.
e.g "http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login/?next=/payment/"
Also when I back out of that page I'm logged in

I've tried in the view 
if user:
login(request, user)
return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))

and added

to the login.html

Login.html

```
{% block content %}
<div style="max-width: 300px; margin: auto;">
<h2 style="text-align: center; font-size: 45px;">Login</h2>
<form class="site-form"  method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    <button type="submit" style="background: #FC5C00; border: 0; color: #fff; font-size: 1.3em; display: block;margin: 0 auto;">Login</button>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            #login user
            user = form.get_user()
            login(request,user)
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST.get('next'))
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = AuthenticationForm()
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',{'form':form})
```

blog view

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def blog_detail(request, slug):
    #return HttpResponse(slug)#Return the slug urls for the detail pages
    blog = Blog.objects.get(slug=slug)
    return render(request, 'blog/blog_detail.html', {'blog':blog})
```

All I need it to do is login to the page that has @login_required tag and show the page once it's logged in

Thanks

Comment: I don't see a `@login_required` tag on the view function.

Comment: I forgot to add the blog views

Comment: It's to open the detailed blog post